# Running Python Code in Parallel across multiple boxes

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have 10 big datasets, My python code loads these as pandas dataframe and preprocesses it to produce a final csv file. I have a column category in each of the dataframe. Earlier I was running over 1 category, and i was able to run my entire file in approx 10 mins. But Now, I am working on 23 categories. When I am trying to run my code now, it is taking huge amount of time.

I have an EMR cluster with 30 hosts. I am able to divide my dataset in 23 files for each dataset for example, first dataset would be like - 
first_dataset_category_1, first_dataset_category_2.
This way I will divide all my datasets into these categories. 
Is there a way, I can run each of my category over a host independently and store the output. 
Later, I can merge all 23 outputs into 1.

Note - All my code is written using Pandas, So I can not port it into spark straight forward, i tried using dask but it is taking too much time to read the data only.

Does anyone has any idea how can i solve my problem ?

Comment: have you tried Hadoop? [here's](https://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/) a quick tutorial.

Comment: you could also look into dask

Comment: Aaron, I am using AWS EMR cluster and can not relate a lot from the document, is there a way for me to understand it a little better in some other document.

Comment: d_kennetz, i looked into dask as written in question as well, and dask is taking too much time to make a dataframe out of data present in s3 in parquet format.